# How to setup go-swagger to generate spec from annotation

Tags: go, swagger, go-swagger

I am following the instructions for generating swagger spec here https://goswagger.io/generate/spec.html.

I have an existing project that needs a UI for the API. I want to use go swagger but I am completely confused https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/tree/master/examples/todo-list
I want to set it up so I add annotations in the code and then run the command swagger generate spec and it would generate the spec
However whenever I run it, it prints `{"swagger":"2.0","paths":{},"definitions":{}}`

This is my command to run it

```
...com/projectFolder]$ swagger generate spec                                                
{"swagger":"2.0","paths":{},"definitions":{}}
```

My project structure is as follows

```
project/ 
  main.go
  api/
    router.go
```

In main.go I have this annotation

```
//go:generate swagger generate spec
package main
```

In router above one of my handlers I have this annotation

```
// swagger:route GET /profile
//
// Gets profile of user
//
//     Produces:
//     - application/json
//     - application/x-protobuf
//
//     Schemes: http, https, ws, wss
//
//     Security:
//       api_key:
//       oauth: read, write
//
//     Responses:
//       default: genericError
//       200: someResponse
//       422: validationError
r.GET("/profile", profileHandler
```

I've been stuck trying to set up an api generator for a while. Any help is much appreciated. If you have experience setting it up, please let me know how you did it

Answer (score 4):

This might be a late answer, but anyway. I faced the same problem and was struggling with go-swagger docs as well; that's what I finally came up with:

`swagger generate` can take input file argument (`-b main.go`, an entry point to your application, from where it automagically finds all the other annotations), and output file (`-o swagger.json`)

So in a whole your command should be like this:

`swagger generate spec -b ./main.go -o swagger.json`

Within my main go file, at the top of it, I have a bit different annotation than you have. It defines the basic project properties like title:

```
// Project title (the dot in the end matters).
//
// Project description.
//
//     Schemes: http
//     Version: 0.1
//
//     Consumes:
//     - application/json
//
//     Produces:
//     - application/json
//
//
// swagger:meta
```

Comment: -b is not a valid flag